# Critical security issue warning on Wordpress site -- "Local file inclusion"

Tags: wordpress, security

```
08/Jul/20 13:33:56  #5406089  CRITICAL     3  195.54.160.115   GET /index.php - Local file inclusion - [GET:fileName = /etc/passwd] - my-domain.com
```

I received this log in my Wordpress NinjaFirewall plugin yesterday. Could somebody please tell me what this is? Does this mean that I have a virus on my website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Local file inclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_inclusion_vulnerability) is an attack on the server. Usually by exploiting weaknesses in some template mechanisms the attacker is able to include servers local files in the servers response. From what I see he wanted to read `/etc/passwd` to learn about the users on your server.

This usually happens due to some vulnerable plugin you have in Wordpress.

EDIT: What the log above does not say is whether:

1. The attack succeeded and was discovered by the firewall,
2. The attack was discovered and prevented by the firewall,
3. The attack was just discovered by the firewall and not really prevented as there was no vulnerable plugin present. Just some web crawlers are searching for poorly configured Wordpress instances with some default payloads.

I believe point 3 or 2 might be the case. You might want to read through your firewall documentation to understand it better.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. Would reading /etc/passwd give him my password? And how can I find out which plugin is responsible for this?

Comment: No reading passwd will give him the user names. The hashes are in /etc/shadow, but non-admin user may not read this file. Regarding plugins - I don't know how to find it out easily. Check if all your plugins are up to date. If not - update them asap. Feel free to dig through https://www.exploit-db.com/. Check if you find there some of the plugins you are using. Check the official plugin sites if they have documented any warnings. Check the CVE list https://cve.mitre.org/cve/.